# Can I add new variables in a structure by not editing the predefined structure?

Tags: struct, c++14

I wanted to know if I can redefine your structure in my code later without editing the previously defined structure
i.e.
This structure is predefined in my code

```
struct Node
{
    int data; 
    Node *left, *right; 

    Node(int key)
    {
        data = key;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};
```

Bur later I have realised that I need to add another variable *** "int hd" *** to the structure but without editing the code of the given structure.

i.e.

```
struct Node
{
    int hd; // New variable that I have added
    int data; 
    Node *left, *right; 

    Node(int key)
    {
        data = key;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};
```

So can I do that without disturbing or editing the previously defined struct and somehow adding a new variable in the structure?

I am trying to do this problem as I am not able to edit the struct in a competitive programming website.

Comment: That would be redefinition which is not allowed. I'm not sure if that site rules allow you to directly edit that or not. If yes, you should edit that directly. If not, you can create a new struct wrapping that variable and the existing struct and then use that.

Comment: @Azeem
I tried to do that, but I can't edit the main function as well, the main function is using the Node structure to define the tree. If I create a new structure then my main function should be also using the same Node structure that I am using to code.

Comment: Right. You need to add a bit more information / code to present your complete scenario. You can add the problem link here if it's a public one. In case of a private problem e.g. job interview test, you can convert it into a smaller code example highlighting your use-case.

Comment: @Azeem I need to redefine my struct, is that possible in c++?

Comment: That is an error. There can only be one type `X` in its enclosing scope. You need to figure out some other strategy.

Comment: @AyushPant: A better question is why do you *need* to "redefine my struct"? Why do you have to add this member later? This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/); something made you want to do this, and that "something" is what you really need to focus on.